# Custom Theme for NWBC creating issue in Fiori

Tags: themes, sapui5, sap-fiori, netweaver

I've created a custom theme for NWBC (just with a different background image) and it turns out that this is connected to Fiori too.  The theme was created just like the tutorial on this link:
[How to create and assign custom theme to NWBC](http://scn.sap.com/community/netweaver-business-client/blog/2014/05/26/nwbc-and-theme-designer--how-to-create-and-assign-custom-theme-to-nwbc).

When I try to run Fiori, I get the following error:

> 404 (Not found)

at this HTTP request: `GET http://<machine_name>/sap/public/bc/themes/~client-200/~cac…p1hMouOcijKd4xZRPUAZhLJ3E/UI5/sap/m/themes/zsap_goldreflection/library.css`

The name of my new custom theme is zsap_goldreflection and, as it appears, the file `library.css` (and also `library-parameters.json`) is not being found.

Any idea why?

Thank you.

Regards, Eva

Answer (score 0):

Custom themes support various clients and frameworks (depending on which SAP theme they are based on). 
Your custom theme seems to be based on SAP Gold Reflection: (zsap_goldreflection/library.css).

However, custom themes based on SAP Gold Reflection are not supported by SAPUI5 mobile libraries, which is why there is no css file and the request fails.

One possible solution would be to try to use SAP Blue Crystal as a basis for your custom theme since it supports SAP Fiori (if this is your main use case).
For an overview, please see the following link: [SAP Standard Themes](https://eaexplorer.hana.ondemand.com/_item.html?id=10655#!/facet/112).

Comment: SAP Blue crystal is also a very old theme and depending on your SAPUI5 version (which is based on component SAP_UI version) you should consider using another theme. Best place to check this is in the SAPUI SDK page [Supported Combinations of Themes and Libraries](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/38ff8c27b022475a92b591bcf6262551)